# How to increment pages in URL when web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get transfer data from transfermarkt.com. The data I'm trying to get is listed on 10 pages so I need to increment the page number in URL. I had it working for a page but could not get it to work for another page and I cannot see the difference. There are 10 pages and each page includes 25 five data points. With both code snippets below, I get a total of 250 rows. However, with the second one, page somehow doesnot increment because the output included the data on the first page 10 times. i.e. 1st row = 26th row = 51th row and so on.

Can anyone please tell me what causes this issue?

1) The code that is working fine:

```
players = []
values = []
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1,21):
        r = s.get(f'https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?ajax=yw1&page={page}', headers=headers)
        soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
        players += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .spielprofil_tooltip')]
        values += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .rechts.hauptlink')]
```

2)The code that returns only data on the first page (The lenght of the output list is 250 but data on the first page is repeated 10 times)

```
player_name_15100 = []
age_date_15100 = []
teams_15100 = []
value_fee_15100 = []

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1,11):
        r = s.get(f'https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/neuestetransfers/statistik/plus/?plus=1&galerie=0&wettbewerb_id=L1&land_id=&minMarktwert=15.000.000&maxMarktwert=100.000.000&yt0&page={page}', headers=headers)
        soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
        player_name_15100 += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .spielprofil_tooltip')]
        age_date_15100 += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .zentriert')]
        teams_15100 += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .vereinprofil_tooltip')]
        value_fee_15100 += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .rechts')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and generate the links before hand and make a list out of them, then for every list you can launch a GET request. Whatever links fail can be stored to be analysed later.

I tried to access subsequent pages on the website and the link you are using was not the same when accessing different page numbers.

Try the following approach:

```
import requests as rq

base_uri = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/neuestetransfers/statistik/plus/plus/1/galerie/0/wettbewerb_id/L1/land_id/minMarktwert/15.000.000/maxMarktwert/100.000.000/yt0/page/"

generated_uris = [f"{base_uri}{pnum}" for pnum in range(1, 11)]

# Alternately if on older version of python
# generated_uris = ["{0}{1}".format(base_uri,pnum) for pnum in range(1,11)]

for uri in generated_uris:
    data = rq.get(uri).text
    #do_something_with_the_html
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the link to `f'https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/neuestetransfers/statistik/plus/plus/1/galerie/0/wettbewerb_id/L1/land_id/minMarktwert/15.000.000/maxMarktwert/100.000.000/yt0/page/{page}'`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

player_name_15100 = []
age_date_15100 = []
teams_15100 = []
value_fee_15100 = []

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1,11):
        r = s.get(f'https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/neuestetransfers/statistik/plus/plus/1/galerie/0/wettbewerb_id/L1/land_id/minMarktwert/15.000.000/maxMarktwert/100.000.000/yt0/page/{page}', headers=headers)
        soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
        player_name_15100 += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .spielprofil_tooltip')]
        age_date_15100 += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .zentriert')]
        teams_15100 += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .vereinprofil_tooltip')]
        value_fee_15100 += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .rechts')]

print(f"{len(player_name_15100)} lines")

for i, name in enumerate(sorted(player_name_15100), start=1):
    print(i, name)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I changed the link as you described. However, something weird is going on. When I ran the code, everything works fine except for teams. teams_15100 list is missing 4 teams missing (2 from left, 2 from joined column). Do you have any idea why this might happened?